# Problems with Tkinter in py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, py2exe

I made a a simple GUI program in python with tkinter and attempted to convert it to an .exe using py2exe. However, I've run into a problem. When I try to run the exe it flashes an error very quickly then disapears. So the best I could do was take a screan shot of the error.

How do I go about fixing this?

[image]

**Edit**

Velociraptors, this is my setup file. It's about as basic as it can be. How would I go about integrating **init.tcl** into the code?

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=[r'C:\Python26\Random Password Generator.py'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your `setup.py` script include `init.tcl` in the `data_files` option? The py2exe [list of options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) says that's how you should include images and other required data files.

**Edit:**

Your setup script specifies that your program should be converted to a console exe. If you want a GUI program (which you do, since you're using Tkinter), you need to use the `windows` option:

```
setup(windows=[r'C:\Python26\Random Password Generator.py'])
```

Py2exe should correctly include Tkinter's dependencies. If not, you can manually include `init.tcl`:

```
setup(data_files=['C:\Python26\tcl\tcl8.5\init.tcl'],
      windows=[r'C:\Python26\Random Password Generator.py'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that tcl is installed in `C:\Users\splotchy\lib\tcl8.5` or `C:\Users\lib\tcl8.5`.

If you want to see the error messages for longer, run your program from a command prompt.

Comment: @Anteater: That's why it is failing…

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug on the virutalenv site which suggested the following https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/93

for windows in your directory "C:\Environments\VirtualEnv\Scripts\activate.bat" just add which are set to the right path to TCL and TK for your python version

```
set "TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5" 
set "TK_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tk8.5"
```

> restart your cmd or shell

I believe that the TCL location have changed from there default ones.